# Unexpected token 'a'

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Using jQuery I have made the following JSON data:

```
[{"name":"date","value":"24-05-2013"},{"name":"omschrijving","value":""}]
```

This is all valid JSON, but when I try to fire the data using jQuery it is giving me the following error:

> Unexpected token A

Here you can see the AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "modules/rma/ajaxhandler.php",
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: goededata,
        dataType: 'json',
        succes: function(data) { alert(data); },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert( textStatus + " " + errorThrown); }
    }).done(function() {
    });
```

ajaxhandler.php contains the following lines:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();

/**
 * Ajaxhandler
 *
 */

print_r($_POST);

echo json_decode($_POST['data']);
?>
```

The data that needs to be sent is made the following way:

```
var allFields = $( [] ).add( date ).add( omschrijving ).add( klachtomschrijving ).add(status).add(artikelnummer).add(klantid).add(meldidrepro).add(meldidaankoop).add(leverancier).add(inkoopregelid).add(serienummer);`

var goededata = JSON.stringify(allFields.serializeArray());
```

How can I correct this error?

Comment: Post the complete JSON string.. should be an issue with data somewhere.

Comment: Try running your JSON through [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.org/) to make sure it's *truly* valid.

Comment: The "A" is the "A" in Array that the print_r is returning. A JSON dataType MUST have a valid JSON response body. I.E. JSON and only JSON.

Comment: @Vega [{"name":"date","value":"17-05-2013"},{"name":"omschrijving","value":""},{"name":"klachtomschrijving","value":""},{"name":"status","value":""},{"name":"artnr","value":""},{"name":"klantid","value":""},{"name":"meldidrepo","value":""},{"name":"meldidaankoop","value":""},{"name":"inkoopregelid","value":""},{"name":"serienummer","value":""}]

Comment: @MattiasBuelens It validates alright, no errors seem to be in them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can not use `print_r` because you are requesting json. The Server-Response is not valid. Comment out the `print_r` call and it should work.

The unexpected token 'a' comes from the output of `print_r`:

```
array(
  ...
)
```

You could use an extra key for debugging:

```
echo json_decode(array(
  'data' => $_POST['data'],
  'debug' => print_r($_POST, true), // note the second parameter for print_r
));
```

on the client side you work with `response.data` and your debug output is in `response.debug'.

But, why not simply log debug output on the server side into a file?

The `error_reporting(E_ALL);` will be a problem too.

It's always a good idea to set the response type:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Comment: @JanDvorak This doesn't change anything either

Comment: @Besnik Alright did that, but now it gave me an 'Unexpected token <'. It's obviously still going wrong somewhere, however i can't figure out where. I'm trying to post from a form -> ajaxcontroller.php

Comment: @Brainscrewer what do you see if you access the uri `modules/rma/ajaxhandler.php` directly with your browser? You should see json (the browser will provide the response as download if you haven't a plugin installed to show up json)

Comment: @Brainscrewer `session_start();` should be the first, try commenting out the line. Have you take a look into your error.log (e.g. `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log`)?

Comment: Try doing a bit more debugging yourself! Using a web debugger like Firebug, you can inspect the AJAX traffic and see the request as well as the received response. You need to make sure that response *only* consists of *valid* JSON data. If you still can't find the problem, try posting the full details of the request and response as given by the debugger.

Answer (score 3):

Chances are your print_r is breaking the expected return call from your AJAX request. Also I don't see where any post data was getting thrown. What I would expect to have happen here is an empty alert box. comment our the print_r

Comment: I've removed the print_r, but now it gives me an 'unexpected token <'

Comment: @Brainscrewer make sure to set `header('Content-type: application/json');`

Comment: you are json decoding, you need to encode it. Setting the content type has nothing to do with the error you are getting